# How to discover and list static libraries used by a software in Linux?

Tags: linux, compile, libraries, reverse-engineer

**Background**: We have a third-party vendor software for our Linux distribution that we are currently testing on `lubuntu`. We have the installation files and an `install.sh` shell script that installs the necessary binaries for the software in the correct directories.

We would like to determine which static libraries are being used internally by this software (so we can tell if they are outdated and introduce vulnerabilities in our environment).

**What we have done so far**: we looked at `ldd` but it only lists shared or dynamic libraries. Same with `objdump`. We used `strings` to look at the strings hidden in some of these binaries to see signs of library version numbers and such. But this is a very time-consuming and inefficient process for large binaries.

**Question**: How can we discover and list static libraries used in a software under the Linux environment?

Comment: If the vendor removed all linking information from the resulting binary, then you can't. However, `gcc` often leaves some information. First step is to look at the available sections in the binary with `objdump -afh /your/file`, please edit question with output.

Comment: Given what you have tried already, You need to [Reverse Engineer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) whole thing. Also you can get some or any useful info with [readelf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html). Best of Luck !

Comment: Analyzing executables for out-dated static libraries is waste of time. Simply ask the software manufacturer if your software version is safe or if there are any updates. It's not reliable to say that an out-dated static library is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### How can we discover and list static libraries used in a Linux program?

> `ldd <exe filename>` shows dynamically linked libraries
>
> `nm <exe filename>` shows the symbols in the file.
>
> To see which symbols come from static libraries requires running `nm`
>   against those libraries to get a list of the symbols (functions, etc.)
>   in them, then comparing them to what your list of symbols from `nm <exe filename>`.
>
> You compare lists with the `comm` command. See `man comm` for details.
>
> This was taken from this forum [here](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/linux-programming/71132-static-library-how-do-i-list.html).

Source [Get list of static libraries used in an executable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1124588/3536342), answer by [DrAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/72791/dral)

Comment: `nm` says "no symbols" for all the binaries that we have tried it on for the software so far.

Comment: Also, as a comment on that answer says: "If its an unknown binary, we don't know what libraries are present. So "running nm against those libraries " sounds self defeating."

Comment: Why don't you just ask the vendor?